# When adding background image : Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton

Tags: java, android, android-drawable

I'm not sure what's exactly causing this issue issue, but whenever I add an image resource as a background for my ImageButton I get the same error. The app just started so there's barely any code. Here is the error:

```
05-28 12:22:08.158 7186-7186/com.example.myname.appname E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myname.appname/com.example.litmo.appname.HomeScreen}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #22: Error inflating class android.widget.ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106)
    at com.example.myname.appname.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
    at com.example.myname.appname.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:503)
    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:356)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:800)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3364)
    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:121)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:87)
    at android.widget.ImageButton.<init>(ImageButton.java:83)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:249) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:106) 
    at com.example.myname.appname.HomeScreen.onCreate(HomeScreen.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".HomeScreen"
    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/homescreen_view">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100.0dp"
        android:layout_height="25.0dp"
        android:text="Help"
        android:id="@+id/instructionsButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#05ffda"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:longClickable="true" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/soundEnable_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
        android:background="@drawable/musicoff" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:text="Highscores"
        android:id="@+id/highscores_button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textColor="#05ffda" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:text="Play Game"
        android:id="@+id/startGame_button"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
        android:textColor="#05ffda"
        android:layout_marginTop="175dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here's the java code:

```
import android.media.Image;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home_screen, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that `musicoff` exists in your drawable folder?

Comment: yes, it is in my drawable folder as a .png

Comment: Your image have big size. Try resize image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your code and it works for me. so i think your problem is your `musicoff` drawable and exactly the size of it.

Try to change this drawable size or try with another drawable image and it will work.

Comment: dd you change the size? or change anything?

Comment: i try another drawable. in fact i had the same problem before. so try with another drawable or change your drawable size. Lets me know if it works

Comment: I'm still getting the same error. What is the size of the file you're using?

Comment: try this one for example [icon](https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_accessibility)